# Purpose of vertical lines beside number orriented vertically in Python

Tags: python, notepad++

I'm just new in python but have 2 years in VBA programming. 
The editor (IDE) I'm using the notepad++ and just wondering about the vertical lines beside the numbers oriented vertically as you can see in the attached image. The lines that I'm referring were encircled in red. Can you please let me know what is the main purpose of these lines.

[image]

Comment: Notepad++ shows Python functions to you!

Comment: This feature is known as [code folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding).

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the input, i find this code folding feature very useful. I'm just new in notepad++ and just wondering how to turn it ON or OFF. When in go to the Settings>Style Configurator then selected the Global Style (Under Language) then under style i selected Fold Active and when in press the save botton. it didn't work. Am i missing something? Thanks

Comment: I just googled this code folding feature and learned that there is a Plugin called Indent by fold. just wondering if you guys can give me a download link for 64bit indent by fold plug in, thank very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can click the minus sign to collapse the code. It doesn't modify the code at all. Just allows you to view your code better.

The line just shows the lines that will be collapsed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, by the looks of it, the minus sign happens whenever there is a new task/statement. And when you have series of statements then these lines/minus signs were interconnected with each other and breaks whenever a particular task ends. my question is what if you have set of task and these lines are for some reason not interconnected does it mean I may end up with erroneous result or more likely end up error?

Comment: No the lines only span a function so that's why they are disconnected. The minus sign pops up on indent for python. It has nothing to do with errors.